# PHP: Add every loop a new div

Tags: php, loops, foreach, count

What I'm trying to do is to add for every loop a new div.

```
<?php
 $f_count = 0; //Is this right?
 foreach ($this->items as $item) {
  <div>
   //stuff
  </div>
  if ($f_count++ == 1) { //Is this right?
   //mystuff1 here 
  }
  if ($f_count++ == 2) { //Is this right?
   //mystuff2 here 
  }
 }
?>
```

So every loop needs to have an own menu item which I create in "mystuff".
Regards!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you keep track of the variable inside the foreach loop.

I find it easier to read and debug as you know what iteration you are on if something goes wrong.

```
<?php

$counter = 0;

foreach(range(1,10) as $i) {
    $counter++;

    if($counter === 1) {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

I haven't run your code but I think I see an issue

`$f_count = 0;` that's looking ok

`if($f_count++ == 1)` this is going to compare the original value of `f_count` and then increment it, so after the comparison it will become 1.

Same thing for the next one, so they may all equate to true, or maybe non of them will ever work... who knows... Just keep track of it and increment

Comment: I tried your solution. Thanks for that be the way. But it doesn't work. The $f_count stop after just 2 loops are created. Because in my original file I using a break, after to showing just 3 items, I need a working 3 counts, which every count has its own menu item. I forgot to say that also the new divs that I need for every loop, that these need to be outside the loop. Otherwise, the menu will be corrupt or not working.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you want something like this, the important part is:

- Use $key => $item, the $key will be 0,1,2,3,4, so basically a counter for you to use!
- You can check whether is 1,3,5 by using `if ($key %2 === 1)`, and 0,2,4,6 by `if ($key %2 === 0)`
- You need to close the PHP tag before your HTML elements

===============

```
<?php
 //$f_count = 0; //No need this

 $items = ["first", "second", "third"];//I used $items, you can keep using $this->items
 foreach ($items as $key => $item) {
  ?>
  <div>
   //stuff
  </div>
<?php
  if ($key %2 === 1) { //1,3,5,7......
?>
<div>
 //mystuff1 here 
</div>
<?php   
  } else { //2,4,6,8
?>  
<div>
   //mystuff2 here 
</div>
<?php  
  }
 }
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for this, but I have a maximum of 3 items because of a break I using. So how I can use your solution? Also,  It needs outside, otherwise the menu will not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, guys, but the problem was creating inside a loop an menu item which was not a smart idea unless you don't use javascript, but in this case, I was using javascript.

So I was searching around in me php file and I found something helpful.

```
<?php if (count($this->items) <= 1) {
  //stuff
} ?>
<?php if (count($this->items) <= 2) {
  //stuff
} ?>
<?php if (count($this->items) > 3 //if there are more than 3 items) {
  //stuff
} ?>
```

I tested i clearly and it seems its working.